# How to focus crop image in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

According to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#resizemode), the react native's `Image` component support the following `resizeModes`:

'cover', 'contain', 'stretch', 'repeat', 'center'

If the image is larger then the `Image` component, the `center` mode fits the image in the `Image` in the component by uniformly scaling the image such that the center point of the image is in center of the `Image` component.

I would like to know if there is a hack or a solution in which  we can define a custom point (say 0,300) as a focus point such that it is the center of the `Image` view.

What I want to achieve is somewhat like focus crop in `fresco`, but should also work for IOS.

Answer (score 9):

I think  you need to handle like this

```
const CroppedImage = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={[
          {
            overflow: 'hidden',
            height: this.props.cropHeight,
            width: this.props.cropWidth,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'
          },
          this.props.style
        ]}
      >
        <Image
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: this.props.cropTop * -1,
            left: this.props.cropLeft * -1,
            width: this.props.width,
            height: this.props.height
          }}
          source={this.props.source}
          resizeMode={this.props.resizeMode}
        >
          {this.props.children}
        </Image>
      </View>
    );
  }
});
```

Look at this example 
[Link](https://github.com/walmartlabs/react-native-cropping/blob/master/example/animcrop.js)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. All the search terms I could think of led to cropping the image in the "image processing and creating a new file" sense. This answer uses styling properties to change the viewable area of an image.

Answer (score 5):

React-Native has a built-in API to handle image cropping, [ImageEditor](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imageeditor.html). It makes image cropping fairly simple. See the function below for an example.

The inputted image takes the form of a URI. The image is cropped, and a URI pointing to a cropped image is provided (the image is housed via React-Native's [ImageStore](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagestore.html) API). Subsequently use this URI to display the cropped image as you wish.

```
// Make sure you import ImageEditor from react-native!
async cropImage(){
    // Construct a crop data object. 
    cropData = {
        offset:{x:0,y:0}, 
        size:{width:20, height:20},
    //  displaySize:{width:20, height:20}, THESE 2 ARE OPTIONAL. 
    //  resizeMode:'contain', 
    }
    // Crop the image. 
    try{
        await ImageEditor.cropImage(uri, 
            cropData, (successURI) => {Something awesome with successURI!}, 
            (error) =>{console.log('cropImage,',error)}
        )
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log('Error caught in this.cropImage:', error)
    }
}
// End of function.
```

Comment: I have other requirement of capturing a part of Image at required position using (x, y, width, height). This Answer helped me :) Thank you.